# Computing first three non-zero terms of the bivariate Taylor series

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> I am trying to find the first three non-zero terms of the bivariate Taylor series of
> $$
> f(x,y) = \sin(\cos(x)−1 +y)
> $$
> around the point $(0,0)$.

I know that I should differentiate it. But I just wondered, is there another solution for this function. When I see a term like $e^x$ differentiation is more useful I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the taylor series of $\sin$ and $\cos$:

$\sin u = u - \frac16u^3+O(u^5)$
$\cos x = 1-\frac12x^2+O(x^4)$

So to evaluate the first three non-zero terms of $\sin(\cos x - 1 + y)$, set $u=y-\frac12x^2$ in the expansion for $\sin u$. You will only need the first term in the expansion of $u^3$. In this particular case, this method is much simpler than differentiating.

(By the way, what *are* the first three non-zero terms of a general Taylor series in two variables? What is the order of the terms in $x^2,xy$, and $y^2$? In this case it doesn't matter, because two of those are zero. But in general you would have to say something like "up to second-order terms" or some such.)

Comment: This is very useful and more fun. Thank you..